# How to access data on a `through` table with Bookshelf

Tags: javascript, node.js, bookshelf.js

I am using [BookshelfJS][bookshelfjs] for my ORM and am wondering how to access data on a `though` table.

I have 3 Models, `Recipe`, `Ingredient` and `RecipeIngredient` which joins the two.

```
var Recipe = BaseModel.extend({
  tableName: 'recipe',

  defaults: { name: null },

  ingredients: function () {
    return this
      .belongsToMany('Ingredient')
      .through('RecipeIngredient')
      .withPivot(['measurement']);
  }
}));

var Ingredient = BaseModel.extend({
  tableName: 'ingredients',

  defaults: { name: null },

  recipes: function () {
    return this
      .belongsToMany('Recipe')
      .through('RecipeIngredient');
  }
}));

var RecipeIngredient = BaseModel.extend({
  tableName: 'recipe_ingredients',

  defaults: { measurement: null },

  recipe: function () {
    return this.belongsToMany('Recipe');
  },

  ingredient: function () {
    return this.belongsToMany('Ingredient');
  }
}));
```

I then attempt to retrieve a `Recipe` along with all the `Ingredients` however cannot work out how to access `measurement` on the `RecipeIngredient`.

```
Recipe
  .forge({
    id: 1
  })
  .fetch({
    withRelated: ['ingredients']
  })
  .then(function (model) {
    console.log(model.toJSON());
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

Return:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Delicious Recipe",
  "ingredients": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Tasty foodstuff",
      "_pivot_id": 1,
      "_pivot_recipe_id": 1,
      "_pivot_ingredient_id": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

With no `measurement` value.

I had thought that the `.withPivot(['measurement'])` method would have grabbed the value but it does not return any additional data.

Have I missed something or misunderstood how this works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why you want to use `through`. If it's just a basic many-to-many mapping, you can achieve this by doing the following:

```
var Recipe = BaseModel.extend({
  tableName: 'recipe',

  defaults: { name: null },

  ingredients: function () {
    return this
      .belongsToMany('Ingredient').withPivot(['measurement']);
  }
}));

var Ingredient = BaseModel.extend({
  tableName: 'ingredients',

  defaults: { name: null },

  recipes: function () {
    return this
      .belongsToMany('Recipe').withPivot(['measurement']);;
  }
}));
```

You don't *need* an additional model for junction table. Just be sure to define a junction table in your database as `ingredients_recipe` (alphabetically joining the name of tables!). Or , you can provide your own custom name to `belongsToMany` function for what the junction table should be named. Be sure to have `ingredients_id` and `recipe_id` in `ingredients_recipe`

This is pretty much it. Then you can do

```
Recipe
  .forge({
    id: 1
  })
  .fetch({
    withRelated: ['ingredients']
  })
  .then(function (model) {
    console.log(model.toJSON());
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.error(err);
  });
```