# BookshelfJS: Is it possible to reformat data from `withPivot`

Tags: javascript, json, rest, bookshelf.js

I'm using Bookshelf to create a fairly simple RESTful API and would like to return a consistent camelCase format while using underscore_database_columns.

I am using the [`format`](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-format) and [`parse`](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-parse) methods from the documentation to do this successfully with the exception of `withPivot` data.

*All code is simplified from my project so please forgive any syntax errors etc, they may not exist in my real code*

I have two models, `Recipe` and `Ingredient`.

```
var Recipe = BaseModel.extend({
  tableName: 'recipe',

  defaults: { name: null },

  ingredients: function () {
    return this
      .belongsToMany('Ingredient')
      .withPivot(['measurement', 'sort_order']);
  }
}));

var Ingredient = BaseModel.extend({
  tableName: 'ingredients',

  defaults: { name: null },

  recipes: function () {
    return this
      .belongsToMany('Recipe');
  }
}));
```

I am querying with the following:

```
Model
  .forge({
    id: 1
  })
  .fetch({
    withRelated: ['ingredients']
  })
  .then(function (model) {
    return res.json(model.toJSON());
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    return done(err);
  });
```

Which returns:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Yummy Thing",
  "ingredients": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Food Stuff",
      "_pivot_ingredient_id": 1,
      "_pivot_recipe_id": 1,
      "_pivot_measurement": "Loads",
      "_pivot_sort_order": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see the `_pivot` data is snake_case as is the `.withPivot(['measurement', 'sort_order'])` as it is pointing to table column names rather than attributes.

Is there any way to easily reference to and return pivot data as camelCase?

I've overridden `toJSON` which works fine but feels wrong given that the base models are using camelCase by default.

```
toJSON: function () {
  var data = BaseModel.prototype.toJSON.apply(this, arguments);
  data.ingredients && (data.ingredients = data.ingredients.map(this.parse));
  return data;
}
```

I'm open to using `through` models but I [couldn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30411367/how-to-access-data-on-a-through-table-with-bookshelf) out how to return the `through` table data with the fetch.  (I'm not set on the the above JSON format so long as all the data is there in some form.)