# How to access data on a join table that has additional one to many relations

Tags: mysql, node.js, bookshelf.js

Hi I have almost the same issue as this previous asked question [How to access data on a `through` table with Bookshelf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30411367/how-to-access-data-on-a-through-table-with-bookshelf) but instead of a value measurement i hava key to table with unit ( L, Kg, mg, ml and so one ) that is attached to the RecipeIngredient table. what i want to have is similar but with my unit? like this:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Delicious Recipe",
  "ingredients": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Tasty foodstuff",
      "_pivot_id": 1,
      "_pivot_recipe_id": 1,
      "_pivot_ingredient_id": 1,
      "_pivot_amount": 10,
      "Unit": "kg"
    }]
}
```

My many to many table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Ingredients_Recipe` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Recipe_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Ingredient_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `amount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Unit_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `Ingredient_id` (`Ingredient_id`),
KEY `Unit_id` (`Unit_id`),
KEY `Recipe_Ingredients_ibfk_1` (`Recipe_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

And my Unit table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Units` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `unit` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY `unit` (`unit`),
KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

My Recipe table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Recipe` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'identifier',
  `name` varchar(254) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Name of the recipe',
  `description` text NOT NULL COMMENT 'Recipe description',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

and my Ingredient table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Ingredients` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(254) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

My Recipe model looks like this

```
module.exports = Bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'Recipe',

  ingredients: function() {
    var Ingredient = require("./Ingredient");

    return this.belongsToMany(Ingredient);
  }
});
```

and my get request looks like this:

```
 Recipe.forge({id: "1"})
    .fetch({withRelated: ["ingredients"]})
    .then( function (recipe) {
      resp.json({error: false, data: recipe.toJSON()});
  })
    .otherwise(function (err) {
    resp.status(500).json({error: true, data: {message: err.message}});
  });
```

If you run this i will get a json response the looks like this:
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Delicious Recipe",
      "ingredients": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "Tasty foodstuff",
          "_pivot_id": 1,
          "_pivot_recipe_id": 1,
          "_pivot_ingredient_id": 1,
        }]
    }

but i want to add

```
"_pivot_amount": 10,
"Unit": "kg"
```

in the ingredients object.

how do i do that?

Regards

What i try to do is a cookbook app. I am using node.js as restAPI server and when i sending a GET request, what i want is to get recipe with ingredients and amount of the ingredient and with what unit the amount is in.

Comment: Exactly what is the problem you are having? If you show us what you have tried so far & explain what doesn't work as you expect - then we can try to help you. Maybe some example data with expected results.

Comment: PaulF i have added som more information about my problem,

Comment: Look at [`withPivot`](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Collection-instance-withPivot).

Comment: Rhys. withPivot will just give me the id of unit table but i want to have Units.unit not just Units.id

Answer (score 0):

I use a little library called bookends https://city41.github.io/bookends/ and basically does what you want in a fast way